# Is it ok to seek kafka consumer to the beginning of the topics partition and poll again all the records

Tags: java, apache-kafka

I have a kafka application with multiple producers and consumers, where I produce records to one topic and after some time I consume group of records from the same topic ( for example 5 records ) and after that I need to get the last record for the given key from the second topic, update it with the new 5 records from the first topic and produce again to the second topic the updated value.

To do this, I need to seek the second topics partition to the beginning, find last record produced for the given key and commit the offset back to the end and after I make an update again produce new record to the same partition with the same key. Is that right thing to do? The application will be used from multiple users when they at the same time update the records for the same key.

I also read about compacted topics but didn't quite understand the meaning of compaction, can compaction save only the last record for the key and delete all previous records immediately when I produce the new one(so I can keep ONLY the last record for each key because I don't need other records), and can you suggest me what is the bast way to structure my application?

Comment: Why would you need to iterate the whole topic again? Just store the last received message for each key. Or use `Create Table` with KSQL which does that IIUC.

Comment: It sounds like you're trying to write your own streaming processing framework, which already exists in Kafka Streams API, KSQL etc. With this you can join between streams, perform stateful calculations and aggregations, and so on.

Comment: Thank you, I'm new with kafka, can you show me some KSQL examples in java or spring boot, will I be able to get all records ever produced for the same key from one topic, because in third topic I need to save all the records one by one and they will be needed as well, besides the last record from the second topic to produce in the first topic, I hope you understood me.

Comment: One more thing, the message gets bigger and bigger on every update on the first topic, when It reaches size bigger than max.message.bytes it won't be able to be stored in the store, is it okay to increase max.message.bytes value? And What would you suggest me to do? Thank you very much for your help.